# Cake PHP 2 associated model not saving

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm working in a legacy Cake PHP 2 project and have a model with some defined relationships. My request data I need to map as it's got other model names in it, so I'm doing this in my new model's `beforeSave` method.

When I try to save, it's saving the upper-most `ApplicationVersionFive` model just fine, but the related models such as `ApplicationPaydayVersionFive` just aren't saving and I have no idea why, it should be saving because my tables are configured:

My tables have a prefix in the `database.php` file.

- model: `ApplicationVersionFive`, table: `tlp_application_version_fives`
- model: `ApplicationPaydayVersionFive`, table: `tlp_application_payday_version_fives`

**ApplicationVersionFive model**

```php
<?php
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http', 'HttpResponse');

class ApplicationVersionFive extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'ApplicationVersionFive';

    public $hasMany = array('RedirectVersionFive','ApplicationPromotionVersionFive', 'ApplicationApiLinkVersionFive');

    public $hasOne = array('ApplicationResponseVersionFive','ApplicationPaydayVersionFive','ApplicationInstallmentVersionFive','ApplicationSecuredVersionFive','ApplicationDebtmgmtVersionFive','ApplicationReclaimVersionFive', 'ApplicationPaydayIcicleHashVersionFive');

        /*
        ** Perform something before a model saves
        ** https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave
        */
        public function beforeSave($åoptions = array()) {
                $application = $this->data;

                $this->data = [
                        'ApplicationVersionFive' => $application['ApplicationVersionFive']['Application'],
                        'ApplicationPaydayVersionFive' => $application['ApplicationVersionFive']['ApplicationPayday'],
                        'ApplicationResponseVersionFive' => $application['ApplicationVersionFive']['ApplicationResponse'],
                        'ApplicationPaydayIcicleHashVersionFive' -> $application['ApplicationVersionFive']['ApplicationPaydayIcicleHash']
                ];

                // continue with save attempt
                return true;
        }
}
```

**ApplicationPaydayVersionFive model**

```php
<?php
class ApplicationPaydayVersionFive extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'ApplicationPaydayVersionFive';
    public $belongsTo = 'ApplicationVersionFive';
}
```

Called via:

```php
$this->ApplicationVersionFive->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

What am I missing to get my linked models to save?

I should also be seeing the Application's model ID saved into the `application_version_five_id` column on my Payday model but I'm not:

[image]
[image]

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_? (I see no SQL above. Do you expect an SQL answer?)

Comment: Why do you have a “å” in the $options arg of beforeSave? Take a look to this line public function beforeSave($åoptions = array()) {

Comment: Did you check if you don’t have validation errors? I meant, you could add an exit in the beforeSave to make sure that the callback method is called. If not… you could have some validation errors